# Pluralization issue in help center privilege page on closing and reopening questions, on sites which only require a single vote to close questions

Tags: feature-request, bug, vote-to-close, help-center, plurals

(While at the moment this issue only applies to Hardware Recommendations, I'm posting this here rather than on their meta since all help pages are fed from a global template, and there is at least one [active feature request](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/would-single-vote-closure-be-helpful-here) to enable single-vote closure on another site.)

On sites that only require one close vote to (bindingly) close a question, the [help center page on the privilege to close questions](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) has a pluralization issue, and contains text that isn't relevant:

> It takes **1 close votes** to reach the closing threshold (except for duplicate questions, which can be marked as duplicate with a single vote from a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that question's current tags, unless that user participated in editing the tags).

There are two issues:

- First, the pluralization issue: "1 close votes" should be "1 close vote".
- Second, the entire part in parentheses isn't relevant on such sites: single-vote closure by a dupehammer user isn't an exception, but the general rule for all users who can close questions (dupehammer or not).

Can the page please be programmed to omit the 's' at the end of "votes", as well as the entire part in parentheses, if the site's closing threshold is equal to just 1 vote?

Comment: The page is not programmed. It is just a post, same as a question, that happens to have some {{inserts}} that get processed for it. The only solution here would be to create manual overrides of that article for any site that only requires one vote, but we are usually reluctant to do that because then any change that gets made to the global article has to also be made on every single override page. :/ Alternatively, rewrite it to not need a pluralization fix and be more relevant to all sites.

Comment: You could make the S an insert as well right? For vote count greater then 1 make the insert an S, otherwise it is nothing.